# C# How get download file name - Selenium(chrome)

Tags: c#, selenium, web-crawler

I use selenium for asp.net crawler
Encountered a problem.

I am downloading multiple files and need to get the name of the completed file in real time.

How do I need to implement it.
Thank you for your answer.

```
IWebElement tableElementaa = _driver.FindElement(By.Id($"cph_gvS02_btnDown_{i - 1}"));
tableElementaa.Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Know that Selenium see's downloading files as an antipattern. They recommend getting the files directly from the server using packages specific for that. But sometimes you really need that download...

First specify tour download directory when starting the browser. Get all files BEFORE the click.
Click
Wait until a new file appeats without .tmp on the end. Sample just waits 5s.

```
options.addOption("download.default_directory", "c:\\Test\\")
var before = Directory.GetFiles("c:\\Test\\");
//do click
Thread.Sleep(5000); // add fancy while with timer here
var newFile = Directory.GetFiles("c:\\Test\\").FirstOrDefault(e=>!before.Contains(e));
```